# 8 Queens on a Chessboard

Tags: java, n-queens

I am a beginner and I am creating a program which will place 8 queens on a chessboard.
I must:

1) Create a blank chessboard (8X8 2D array of integers, all 0's)
2) Using a loop, ask the user for 8 locations on the board, replace the 0 with a 1 at this location
3) Display the final board

I do not have to include any error checking or checking for duplicate locations.

My code does not store the values properly.
Only the last one gets printed correctly.

```
package chessboard;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class ChessBoard {

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int chessBoardArray[][] = new int[8][8];

    for (int z = 0; z < 8; z++) {
        int rowValue = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the row value (1-8)"));
        int columnValue = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the column value (1-8)"));
        int rowValueFinal = rowValue - 1;
        int columnValueFinal = columnValue - 1;

        for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
                if (i == rowValueFinal && j == columnValueFinal) {
                    chessBoardArray[i][j] = 1;
                } else {
                    chessBoardArray[i][j] = 0;

                }
            }
        }
    }

    for (int k = 0; k < 8; k++) {
        if (k < 7) {
            System.out.print(chessBoardArray[0][k]);
        } else {
            System.out.println(chessBoardArray[0][k]);
        }
    }
    for (int k = 0; k < 8; k++) {
        if (k < 7) {
            System.out.print(chessBoardArray[1][k]);
        } else {
            System.out.println(chessBoardArray[1][k]);
        }
    }
    for (int k = 0; k < 8; k++) {
        if (k < 7) {
            System.out.print(chessBoardArray[2][k]);
        } else {
            System.out.println(chessBoardArray[2][k]);
        }
    }
    for (int k = 0; k < 8; k++) {
        if (k < 7) {
            System.out.print(chessBoardArray[3][k]);
        } else {
            System.out.println(chessBoardArray[3][k]);
        }
    }
    for (int k = 0; k < 8; k++) {
        if (k < 7) {
            System.out.print(chessBoardArray[4][k]);
        } else {
            System.out.println(chessBoardArray[4][k]);
        }
    }
    for (int k = 0; k < 8; k++) {
        if (k < 7) {
            System.out.print(chessBoardArray[5][k]);
        } else {
            System.out.println(chessBoardArray[5][k]);
        }
    }
    for (int k = 0; k < 8; k++) {
        if (k < 7) {
            System.out.print(chessBoardArray[6][k]);
        } else {
            System.out.println(chessBoardArray[6][k]);
        }
    }
    for (int k = 0; k < 8; k++) {
        if (k < 7) {
            System.out.print(chessBoardArray[7][k]);
        } else {
            System.out.println(chessBoardArray[7][k]);
        }
    }

}

}
```

Comment: Please [edit] with the output you see vs what is expected

Comment: Your `else` branch overwrites all previous values stored - remove it (and have an initial loop that sets all values of the array to 0)

Comment: @UnholySheep `int[]` already is initialized at 0

Comment: @cricket_007 Oops, been coding too much C lately

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because homework rules of SO

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This loop doesn't need to exist.

You are clearing the entire board and setting only one cell

```
for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
        if (i == rowValueFinal && j == columnValueFinal) {
            chessBoardArray[i][j] = 1;
        } else {
            chessBoardArray[i][j] = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

You should replace that entire loop with

```
chessBoardArray[rowValue - 1][columnValue - 1] = 1;
```

Comment: You could also add an improved output loop to your answer.

Comment: @Blobonat Thought about it, but it's their homework, not mine.